# "Your review progress" showing target badge that I've already received

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

When visiting [/review/first-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers) I was presented with the following on the right side-bar:

[image: screenshot]

On some visits, this is not shown and replaced by "*Your Review Stats*".

Is that a bug, or a feature?

If it's by design, shouldn't it be showing me my progress to the next badge up, i.e. Copy Editor?

P.S. This happens on other review tabs as well; "*Your review stats*" simply gets replaced by "*Your review progress*". I cannot consistenly reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: I cannot see what you see, but I guess it is because I have already the "Strunk & White" badge.

Comment: NOTE: This appears to be here on Meta only. On the other sites it appears correctly.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - here on META I'm seeing the same and I do have the Strunk and White badge.

Comment: @kiamlaluna I too have the stunk & white badge.

Comment: @chrisF I saw that on the main SO site.

Comment: @ChrisF I don't see that on meta too. If I visit "review/first-answers" I see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/w05sO.png).

Comment: @ShawnChin - OK - something odd is happening. I was seeing the page correctly on Stack Overflow, however, I'm now seeing what you've reported here. It appears to be OK on other sites (for the moment).

Comment: Argh… I am kiamlalun**o**.

Comment: Meta appears OK again (version 7.4). Stack Overflow is still wrong (version 7.2). Super User is OK (version 7.3). I think this is still work in progress

Comment: @ChrisF how about now?

Comment: @MarcGravell - still showing the "You need Strunk and White" message. Do I need to hard refresh? The version is still rev 2011.11.7.3

Comment: @ChrisF on which site?

Comment: @MarcGravell - Stack Overflow, though it appears to be working again now. Must have been a caching issue somewhere along the line.

Comment: @ChrisF the versioning is... complex; but 7.3 is indeed "current" and should've worked

Comment: @kiamlaluno sorry, that was a  typo.

Comment: @MarcGravell - indeed it is *now*.

Comment: @ChrisF ah, I see it... gimme 3 minutes...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See, you passed the first test of /review, by correctly noting this, er, *intentional* foible.

(was that at all convincing?)

This should now be resolved. If not, please let me know.

(coughs again quietly... or, in 2 minutes, at least...)

Comment: It is still not fixed; on meta.drupal.stackexchange.com I can read, "[You have edited a total of 81 posts (101% done)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6K6NZ.png)". Should I edit 100 posts to get the "Strunk & White" badge?

Comment: I forgot that the badge is given after editing 80 posts, not 100. I wonder why I keep thinking of 100 posts.

Comment: +1 just for the good humor! :)

Comment: @kiamlaluno It used to be 100.

Comment: @yoda That would explain my mistake. `:-)` Thank you.

Comment: Do community wiki edits count ? I managed to get to 101% by combining suggested edits and community wikis edit. The trick is, if I edit through the review panel a community wiki, it will count. If I go in the question and edit it there it won't. Might be a possible source of remaining issues on this counter.