# 1543% done on reviewer.. wait what?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Your review progress” showing target badge that I've already received](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111205/your-review-progress-showing-target-badge-that-ive-already-received)

So [waffles just rolled out a new badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110698/new-bronze-badge-for-reviewing):

> Reviewer: 300 reviews, over 60 actioned.

Eager to check how far I am, went over to check.

[image: reviewer]

Wonder what the stats on [these guys](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all) would be like!

(PS: Y U TAKE OUT THE COUNTS!?)

Comment: Good to know I'm not the only one confused by that. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111205/134327

Comment: ah, I missed that, voting to close this @ShawnChin