# 106% complete! Strunk and white progress in review pane

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, edit-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Your review progress” showing target badge that I've already received](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111205/your-review-progress-showing-target-badge-that-ive-already-received)

So as far as I know, I haven't made very many edits today. Judging by my history, I have 4 edits and/or retags ("revisions" as it calls them) in the last two days. When I go to [the review page](http://www.stackoverflow.com/review), I see a handy-dandy review progress screen on the side. Here's a snapshot:

[image]

Don't get me wrong. **I'm not saying I should have Strunk and White.** It's quite obvious that I have some retags or some other revisions that do not count towards Strunk and White, or I'd have it by now. And that's fine. I'm just pointing out the sidebar is a bit misleading.

Comment: @yoda now I'm torn. I'm not sure what the proper procedure is. That is flagged as status completed. Should I update them over there? Or is that considered "done" making it appropriate to make a new post.

Comment: I also note that I have a slightly different problem than was reported by Shawn in that post. There, the badge was awarded. For me, I don't have the badge, making it related but unique.

Comment: I'm guessing the change just hasn't been pushed out yet... I guess you could drop a comment to Marc in that post. It's unlikely that they'll answer this again... As for the badge being awarded or not, I'm pretty sure the bug is the same in that it counts your total edits and shows it as a % of 80 edits that count towards S&W

Comment: @yoda unlikely. It's showing as revision rev 2011.11.8.5, which should have contained a fix from yesterday.

Comment: The fact that you haven't received the badge just means that the "Pin Badge On Shirt" job hasn't run yet. Pretty sure this is the same bug. The fact that it's still appearing, however, seems to indicate that "Status-completed" was applied prematurely.

Comment: @josh No, I shouldn't have the badge. That's the issue. I have 85 revisions, but only about 60 or 70 of them are eligible for strunk and white. So I shouldn't have the badge. And, it shouldn't be counting them in the 106%

Comment: @glowcoder In any case, I'm merely speculating here and only Marc knows the answer. I'd leave it upto you whether to leave this question or comment on Marc's answer. Rightly or wrongly, I've voted this a dupe and looks on track to being closed...

Comment: looking into this now ... something is out of sync

Comment: possibly edits on deleted posts, yeah ... that is it

Comment: Well, if you're _certain_ that you don't qualify, then I guess this display is borked in that way, too.

Comment: @waffles That was some ninja bug fixing to the rescue :-) Thanks! My day is no longer shattered into pieces!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just fixed an issue where `Strunk & White` **was not** counting edits on deleted posts, yet the little side bar was.

Now there are 2 cases where the sidebar may be out of sync:

1. We grant badges **at the slowest** once every hour. The sidebar may be indicating you are about to get the badge.
2. We cache the fact you have, or do not have, the badge for 240 seconds.

In future, if you reached more than 100% and have waited an hour, let me know.

Comment: to be deployed today

Comment: For clarification which did you change? Make Strunk & White count deleted posts? Or the side bar?

Comment: side bar ... edits on deleted posts should not be encouraged.

Comment: Are these only edits on posts which are deleted on the time they are edited, or also edits on posts which later got deleted (i.e. the edit didn't help to prevent deletion)?

Comment: posts that got later deleted as well @PaŭloEbermann

Comment: Is that to mean that, as an extension of your comment, that edits on posts that are likely to be deleted are also discouraged since the 'reward' (used loosely) for the work is nulled? It seems to me those are the ones that are most in need of edits.

Comment: @glowcoder not true, we strongly believe in "no dumping". You should not be editing stuff that is spam on our sites. Self deleted in general are an exception.